# cocos2d-x で TiledMapの全レイヤ名を取得する方法について

Tags: cocos2d-x

cocos2d-x ver 3.6 を使用して、下記のコードを書きました。

本件の目的は、
TMXTiledMap 内のレイヤ名を、TMXTiledMap編集者（非プログラマ）が、
自由に名称をつけ、それをプログラム側で読み込めるようにする事がしたいです。

---

```
auto map = TMXTiledMap::create(FileName);

// 地形レイヤを取得する
auto terrainLayer = map->getLayer("Terrain");
if (nullptr== terrainLayer){
    // terrainLayerが存在しない場合
}
```

---

例えば、上記コードの場合は、作成したファイルのレイヤ名"Terrain"にすれば読み込めます。
レイヤ名が不明の状態ではgetLayerは使用出来ず困っています。

下記ページも拝見しましたが、良く分からなかった為、この場で質問させてください。
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.0/d6/d48/classcocos2d_1_1_t_m_x_tiled_map.html

Answer (score 1):

レイヤー名は複数のレイヤーの中から指定のレイヤーを探すために存在します。
当然マップ作成者とプログラマーの間で取り決めが必要です。
でないとどのレイヤーが何を表すのかさっぱりわかりません。
プロパティを追加して何とかする手はありますが普通はしないでしょう。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
折角、お返事をいただいたのですが、私が知りたい事は作業の情報共有についての常識ではなく、タイルレイヤー名の列挙をする手段です。

オブジェクト・レイヤーのグループ名を列挙する関数が存在しながら、タイル・レイヤーのグループ名の列挙の方法が見つからず困っていました。

Comment: 元の質問と全然違くね？

Comment: 本件のタイトルは、「cocos2d-x で TiledMapの全レイヤ名を取得する方法について」です。

どのような部分で質問の違いを感じているのか、私には分かりかねますが、もしも、解決方法をご存知ならば、ご教授ください。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score -1):

結構前の質問なので、解決済みかもしれませんが

```
    auto tileMap = TMXTiledMap::create("ファイル名");
    Vector<Node*> childOfMap = tileMap->getChildren();
    for (auto& child : childOfMap)
    {
        TMXLayer* layer = dynamic_cast<TMXLayer*>(child);
        if(layer != nullptr) {
            const std::string name = layer->getLayerName();
            CCLOG("%s", name.c_str());
        }
    }
```

でどうでしょうか？　勘違いしていたらごめんなさい

Comment: 上記コードはtmxファイル内のレイヤー名をデバッグ出力するものです。